# Get Median and IQR when using the table1 package

Tags: r

Is there a way to get only the median and IQR (as opposed to the mean/median [range] when using the table 1 package? I've seen some things about "render" but unsure how it works

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [How to create a function to display the 25th and 75th percentile (IQR) in table1 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314081/how-to-create-a-function-to-display-the-25th-and-75th-percentile-iqr-in-table1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your own render function. This should take the input vector and return a named character vector that will appear formatted in your table:

```r
render.median.IQR <- function(x, ...) {
  c('', 
    `Mean (SD)` = sprintf("%s (%s)", round(mean(x), 2), round(sd(x), 2)),
    `Median [IQR]` = sprintf("%s [%s, %s]", median(x), 
                             quantile(x, 0.25), quantile(x, 0.75)))
}
```

To use it, we could do:

```r
table1(~Petal.Length, data = iris, render = render.median.IQR)
```

[image]

Note that this is different from the default render function:

```r
table1(~Petal.Length, data = iris)
```

[image]